# Add Images in the Edittext and replace it with another Images whenever user enters

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am new to Android and I have the following requirement.

Please let me know is this feasible.

[image]

Initially EditText will consist of 6 empty circles. When user clicks on first digit the circle fill as given below image. When user clicks on backspace the circle becomes empty.

[image]

Any links or examples or code samples will be helpful.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Post your code and the exact issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the code that solved my issue. The link from @Booger and @Muthuraj helped a lot to build this code

MainActivity.java file

```
package com.app.xyz.activity;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.app.xyz.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnFocusChangeListener, View.OnKeyListener, TextWatcher {

private static final String TAG = "[MainActivity]";

TextView tvHello, tv_one, tv_two, tv_three, tv_four, tv_five, tv_six;

private EditText mPinFirstDigitEditText;
private EditText mPinSecondDigitEditText;
private EditText mPinThirdDigitEditText;
private EditText mPinForthDigitEditText;
private EditText mPinFifthDigitEditText;
private EditText mPinSixthDigitEditText;

private EditText mPinHiddenEditText;
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}

/**
 * Hides soft keyboard.
 *
 * @param editText EditText which has focus
 */
public void hideSoftKeyboard(EditText editText) {
    if (editText == null)
        return;

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MainLayout(this, null));

    init();

    setPINListeners();

}

/**
 * Initialize EditText fields.
 */
private void init() {

    tvHello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHello);

    tv_one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_three);

    tv_two = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_four);

    tv_three = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_five);

    tv_four = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_six);

    tv_five = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_seven);

    tv_six = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_eight);





    mPinFirstDigitEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin_first_edittext);
    mPinSecondDigitEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin_second_edittext);
    mPinThirdDigitEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin_third_edittext);
    mPinForthDigitEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin_forth_edittext);
    mPinFifthDigitEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin_fifth_edittext);
    mPinSixthDigitEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin_sixth_edittext);
    mPinHiddenEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin_hidden_edittext);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

    mPinHiddenEditText.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(mPinHiddenEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);



}


@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    final int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.pin_first_edittext:
            if (hasFocus) {
                setFocus(mPinHiddenEditText);
                showSoftKeyboard(mPinHiddenEditText);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.pin_second_edittext:
            if (hasFocus) {
                setFocus(mPinHiddenEditText);
                showSoftKeyboard(mPinHiddenEditText);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.pin_third_edittext:
            if (hasFocus) {
                setFocus(mPinHiddenEditText);
                showSoftKeyboard(mPinHiddenEditText);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.pin_forth_edittext:
            if (hasFocus) {
                setFocus(mPinHiddenEditText);
                showSoftKeyboard(mPinHiddenEditText);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.pin_fifth_edittext:
            if (hasFocus) {
                setFocus(mPinHiddenEditText);
                showSoftKeyboard(mPinHiddenEditText);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.pin_sixth_edittext:
            if (hasFocus) {
                setFocus(mPinHiddenEditText);
                showSoftKeyboard(mPinHiddenEditText);
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        final int id = v.getId();

        Log.e(TAG, "======================================");

        Log.d(TAG, "mPinHiddenEditText===>"+mPinHiddenEditText.getText());
        Log.d(TAG, "mPinHiddenEditText.getText().length()===>"+mPinHiddenEditText.getText().length());


        switch (id) {
            case R.id.pin_hidden_edittext:
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                    if (mPinHiddenEditText.getText().length() == 6) {
                        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setText("");

                    }
                    else if (mPinHiddenEditText.getText().length() == 5) {
                        mPinFifthDigitEditText.setText("");
                    }
                    else if (mPinHiddenEditText.getText().length() == 4) {
                        mPinForthDigitEditText.setText("");
                    }
                    else if (mPinHiddenEditText.getText().length() == 3) {
                        mPinThirdDigitEditText.setText("");
                    }
                    else if (mPinHiddenEditText.getText().length() == 2) {
                        mPinSecondDigitEditText.setText("");
                    }

                    else if (mPinHiddenEditText.getText().length() == 1) {
                        mPinFirstDigitEditText.setText("");
                    }


                    if (mPinHiddenEditText.length() > 0)
                        mPinHiddenEditText.setText(mPinHiddenEditText.getText().subSequence(0, mPinHiddenEditText.getText().length() - 1));

                    Log.d(TAG, "hidden====>"+mPinHiddenEditText.getText());
                    Log.e(TAG, "======================================");

                    return true;
                }

                break;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    Log.d(TAG, "s.length()===>"+s.length());
    Log.d(TAG, "count===>"+count);
    Log.d(TAG, "s===>"+s.toString());

    if (s.length() == 0) {
        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);
        mPinFifthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);
        mPinForthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);
        mPinThirdDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);
        mPinSecondDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);
        mPinFirstDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);


    } else if (s.length() == 1) {
        mPinFirstDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);

        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);
        mPinFifthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);
        mPinForthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);
        mPinThirdDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);
        mPinSecondDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);



    } else if (s.length() == 2) {
        mPinSecondDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinFirstDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);
        mPinFifthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);
        mPinForthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);
        mPinThirdDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);


    } else if (s.length() == 3) {
        mPinThirdDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinSecondDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinFirstDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);
        mPinFifthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);
        mPinForthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);



    } else if (s.length() == 4) {
        mPinForthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinThirdDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinSecondDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinFirstDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);
        mPinFifthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);



    } else if (s.length() == 5) {
        mPinFifthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinForthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinThirdDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinSecondDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinFirstDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp);



    } else if (s.length() == 6) {
        mPinSixthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinFifthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinForthDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinThirdDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinSecondDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);
        mPinFirstDigitEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_lens_black_24dp);


    }
}

/**
 * Sets default PIN background.
 *
 * @param editText edit text to change
 */
private void setDefaultPinBackground(EditText editText) {
    setViewBackground(editText, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp));
}

/**
 * Sets focus on a specific EditText field.
 *
 * @param editText EditText to set focus on
 */
public static void setFocus(EditText editText) {
    if (editText == null)
        return;



    editText.setFocusable(true);
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    editText.requestFocus();
}



/**
 * Sets listeners for EditText fields.
 */
private void setPINListeners() {

    mPinHiddenEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);

    mPinFirstDigitEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    mPinSecondDigitEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    mPinThirdDigitEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    mPinForthDigitEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    mPinFifthDigitEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    mPinSixthDigitEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

    mPinFirstDigitEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);
    mPinSecondDigitEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);
    mPinThirdDigitEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);
    mPinForthDigitEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);
    mPinFifthDigitEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);
    mPinSixthDigitEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);

    mPinHiddenEditText.setOnKeyListener(this);
}

/**
 * Sets background of the view.
 * This method varies in implementation depending on Android SDK version.
 *
 * @param view       View to which set background
 * @param background Background to set to view
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setViewBackground(View view, Drawable background) {
    if (view == null || background == null)
        return;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        view.setBackground(background);
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    }
}

/**
 * Shows soft keyboard.
 *
 * @param editText EditText which has focus
 */
public void showSoftKeyboard(EditText editText) {
    Log.d(TAG,"showSoftKeyboard"+editText.getText());
    if (editText == null)
        return;


    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);


}

/**
 * Custom LinearLayout with overridden onMeasure() method
 * for handling software keyboard show and hide events.
 */
public class MainLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public MainLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int proposedHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        final int actualHeight = getHeight();

        Log.d("TAG", "proposed: " + proposedHeight + ", actual: " + actualHeight);

        if (actualHeight >= proposedHeight) {

        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
  }


}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pin_content_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="15dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pin_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"

    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pin_first_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:background="@drawable/ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pin_second_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:background="@drawable/ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pin_third_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:background="@drawable/ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pin_forth_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:background="@drawable/ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pin_fifth_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:background="@drawable/ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pin_sixth_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:background="@drawable/ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pin_hidden_edittext"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@null"
    android:inputType="number|numberPassword"
    android:maxLength="6"
    android:textColor="#00000000"
    />


 </LinearLayout>
```

I used drawables for filled (ic_lens_black_24dp) and empty (ic_panorama_fish_eye_black_24dp) circles.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, you simply need to create an onClickListener for each of your number buttons, and keep track of the number of dots that are filled in.  Then for each click event, you will change the dot to be filled in (to be clear, these dots will be 2 drawables, one filled in, the other not filled in, and you will switch the background drawable as appropriate).

Bottom line, this is a pretty simple thing to do, so there likely is not a library that does this.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). In `onTextChanged` get the length of the entered text and color the circles accordingly. 
To fill colors, put the circles in an array of ImageView so that you can manipulate them easily.